# $(34)(123)(456)$ is a cycle. True or False?

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

I know this is basics, and I understand that $(34)(123)(456)$ is a product of cycles which, I found: $(124563)$.
But somehow, I was lost. How do I know if it is indeed a cycle? OR if it isn't? 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: To clarify: what are you asking? How to determine if in general a product of cycles can be expressed as a single cycle? What you've calculated for the permutation in question is indeed true.

Comment: @ah1195o , you've approved that I'm on the right track ,thanks.

Comment: @ah11095o , so since all the elements have been kept track it implies that it is indeed a cycle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are getting a bit long for comments, so:

I'm not sure what you mean by 'all elements have been kept track'. For example, if $\Omega = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$, and $\sigma = (123)(45)$ acts on $\Omega$, then all elements of $\Omega$ are accounted for ('kept track'?), but $\sigma$ cannot be expressed as a single cycle.

In general, I suppose to check if a permutation $\sigma$ acting on a set $\Omega$ can be expressed as a single cycle, you need to check if it acts transitively on $\Omega \setminus Fix(\sigma)$. This means that for any two elements $\alpha, \beta \in \Omega$ that are **not** fixed by $\sigma$, there exists $n\geq 1$ such that $\alpha^{\sigma^n} = \sigma^n (\alpha) = β$.

Given an arbitrary permutation expressed as a product of cycles:

$$\sigma=(\alpha_1 \ldots \alpha_{r_1})(\beta_1 \ldots \beta_{r_2})\ldots(\gamma_1 \ldots \gamma_{r_k})$$

if you want to check whether this can be written as a single cycle, you should first check to see whether the cycles are disjoint or not. If we have $\alpha_i = \beta_j$ say, then the cycles are not disjoint and there is a simpler expression. If however all elements of $\Omega$ appearing in the cycles are distinct, then the cycles are disjoint and this is the expression of $\Omega$ in disjoint cycle notation.

Comment: So, even if I were not able to express the permutation as a single cycle, it would still be a cycle? but then disjoint?

Comment: No, a cycle is something of the form $(\alpha_1 \ldots \alpha_r)$; what you're calling a 'single cycle'. Any permutation can be expressed as a *product* of cycles.

Comment: Thank you. Now i understand

Comment: It doesn't make sense to talk about a single disjoint cycle - there are no other cycles for it to be 'disjoint' to. We say a permutation is a *product* of disjoint cycles if it is of the form something like $(123)(45)$. Note that this isn't a cycle - it contains two cycles. However something like $(123)(345)$ isn't written as a product of disjoint cycles since 3 appears in both cycles. The number of cycles of a permutation when it's written as a product of disjoint cycles is the number of non-trivial orbits under that permutation.

Answer (score 2):

$$
(34)(123)(456) = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
1 & 2 & 4 & 3 & 5 & 6 
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
2 & 3 & 1 & 4 & 5 & 6
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 5 & 6 & 4
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Now compose from right to left to get
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
2 & 4 & 1 & 5 & 6 & 3
\end{pmatrix} = (124563)
$$
So what you've got appears to be correct - and yes, it is a cycle!